# Connection between F-Algebras and algebras for a monad

Tags: category-theory, computer-science, monads

I've been reading up on functional programming, and I've come across two "algebra" notions which seem similar:

- An ***F-Algebra*** $F A \rightarrow A$ which captures the signature of the operations of, say, a monoid (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-algebra#Groups).
- An ***algebra for a monad***, $T A \rightarrow A$. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBQnysX7oLI), monoids are presented as algebra for the free monoid monad.

Is there any connection between these two concepts, or are they just superficially similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the one hand, one can answer that $F$-algebras for an endofunctor $F: \mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ are more general than EM-algebras for a monad $T: \mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}$ (EM-algebras = Eilenberg-Moore algebras for a monad $T$) in the sense that: the EM-category for $T$ (i.e. the category of EM-algebras for $T$) is a full subcategory of the category of $T$-algebras.

But there is also another direction meaning that **EM-algebras are more general**: the category of $F$-algebras is itself the EM-category for a particular $T$, if for any $C\in \mathcal{C}$ the functor $G X= FX+C$ has an initial algebra. Inuitively, an EM-algebra for a monad $T$ evaluates finite $T$-terms preserving the laws of the theory and an $F$-algebra evaluates a flat term within the theory of $F$-terms without any further laws to obey.

Let $TC$ be the carrier of the initial $G$-algebra and let $g_C$ be its algebra structure:
$$
g_C: F(TC) + C \longrightarrow TC.
$$
For some $h: C\to D$, define $Th$ by recursion using the $G$-algebra $g_D\cdot (\mathsf{id}+h)$:
$$
\matrix{
&FTC+C& \xrightarrow{g_C} && TC \\
{FTh+C}\swarrow &\quad\quad\searrow& & & \downarrow\rlap{=: Th}
\\
FTD+C &\smash{\xrightarrow{\mathsf{id}+h}}
&FTD+D & \smash{\xrightarrow{g_D}} &TD
}
$$
This diagram also proves that $g_{(-)}$ is natural.

Then one can show that $T$ is a monad on $\mathcal{C}$: its unit is $\eta_C = g_C\cdot \mathsf{inr}: C\to TC$ and its multiplication is defined by recursion again:
$$
\matrix{
FTTC + TC & \xrightarrow{\quad g_{TC}\quad}
& TTC
\\
\llap{F\mu_C+\mathsf{id}_{TC}}\downarrow && \downarrow\rlap{\mu_C}
\\
FTC + TC & \smash{\xrightarrow{[g_C\cdot \mathsf{inl},\mathsf{id}]}} & TC
}
$$
$T$ is called the *free monad on $F$*, which can be intuitively thought of mapping a set $C$ to the finite $F$-terms over $C$. Now there is a one-to-one correspondence between $F$-algebras and EM-algebras for $T$: for any $F$-algebra $a:FA\to A$, we obtain a EM-algebra for $T$ by
$$
FA+A \xrightarrow{[a,\mathsf{id}_A]} A
$$
and conversely any EM-algebra $b: TB\to B$ induces an $F$-coalgebra $b\cdot g_B\cdot \mathsf{inl}\cdot F\eta_B: FB\to B$.

Answer (score 0):

An $F$-algebra is the generalization of an algebra for a monad to the case where have monad $T$ may be an arbitrary endofunctor. Note that the structure of an algebra for a monad is again a map $TA\to A$, not $TA\to T$ as in your question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo, fixed.

Comment: So, yeah, it's clear that every algebra for a monad is also an F-algebra, so it's more a general concept. The encodings of monoids I've seen are quite different in both settings, though

Comment: Well, yeah, why shouldn't they be?